# Latex: Table-enumerate

Tags: latex

I am trying to produce the following table using LaTeX: [image: desired]

at which the numbers are enumerated. So I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{[}1{]}]
\begin{table}
\small
\caption{\textbf{\small{External Documents}}}
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.025\linewidth} | p{0.25\linewidth} | p{0.34\linewidth} |                        p{0.075\linewidth} | p{0.15\linewidth} | p{0.13\linewidth} |}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{Ref.}  
                                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{0.615\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Document Title}}                                                                             & \textbf{Rev.}                                                                     & \textbf{Date }                                                                        & \textbf{Author}                                                       \\ \hline
\item \label{itm:one}   & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                        & Bla                                   & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                    & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                        \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\item \label{itm:two}   &                                                                                   & Bla                               &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\item \label{itm:three}     &                                                                                   & Bla                   &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\item \label{itm:four}  &                                                                                   & Bla                                                           &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\item \label{itm:five}  &                                                                                   & Bla                                       &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
\item \label{itm:six}   & \multirow{2}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                                                        & Bla                                   & Bla                                                                               & NA                                                                                    & \multirow{3}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                    \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
\item \label{itm:seven}     &                                                                                   & Bla                       
            & bla                                                                                   & Bla      &                                            \\ \cline{1-5}
\item \label{itm:eight}     & Bla                                       & Bla           & Bla                                                                                   & Bla                                   &                               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But the output was like this:

[image: output]

I don't understand what I've done wrong in my code. Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't use enumerate items like this - but you also don't need them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{0}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\refstepcounter{foo}[\thefoo]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\caption{\textbf{\small{External Documents}}}
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.025\linewidth} | p{0.25\linewidth} | p{0.34\linewidth} |                        p{0.075\linewidth} | p{0.15\linewidth} | p{0.13\linewidth} |}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{Ref.}  
                                                                                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{0.63\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Document Title}}                                                                             & \textbf{Rev.}                                                                     & \textbf{Date }                                                                        & \textbf{Author}                                                       \\ \hline
\myitem 
\label{itm:one}  
 & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                        & Bla                                   & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                    & \multirow{5}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                        \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\myitem 
\label{itm:two}  
 &                                                                                   & Bla                               &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\myitem 
\label{itm:three}  
   &                                                                                   & Bla                   &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\myitem 
\label{itm:four}  
&                                                                                   & Bla                                                           &                             &                          &                          \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
\myitem 
\label{itm:five}  
&                                                                                   & Bla                                       &                             &                          &                          \\ \hline
\myitem 
\label{itm:six}
   & \multirow{2}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                                                                        & Bla                                   & Bla                                                                               & NA                                                                                    & \multirow{3}{1\linewidth}{Bla}                                    \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
\myitem 
\label{itm:seven}     
&                                                                                   & Bla                       
            & bla                                                                                   & Bla      &                                            \\ \cline{1-5}
\myitem
 \label{itm:eight}
     & Bla                                       & Bla           & Bla                                                                                   & Bla                                   &                               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\ref{itm:two} \ref{itm:eight}

\end{document}
```

[image]